# Is it possible to take a crawled html file, and get information about how a browser would render it?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, browser, render

Examples of stuff I'd like to do:
- process javascript and produce new DOM
- be able to provide information about DOM objects as rendered (e.g. position, size)

Edit: My main concern is if a page contains a large, central flash object (typically a movie or game).

Comment: You could take a look into the source code of one of the tools that do that, e.g. Firebug.

Comment: Rendered on what user agent? what screen resolution? what default fonts? All these things can affect position and size of DOM objects

Answer (score 2):

I guess the only way to do this is to pipe the HTML through a rendering engine, either a real one (like WebKit or Gecko) or something feature-complete enough for your purposes, and then query the resulting DOM about how it looks. Maybe take a look at projects like [webkit2png](http://www.paulhammond.org/webkit2png/) for inspiration.

Comment: webkit2png looks great! any windows version of similar tool ?